# Mails sent through from server delivers in spam after changing the server ip

Tags: email, server, whm, mail-server

I have a big issue in our WHM. Our server ip was blacklisted by baraccuda a week ago. Now it was removed but all emails delivers in SPAM folder. We have tried mamy thing to sort this but unable to fix this problem.

Here is layout of our server.

We have 1 cpannel in whm and it have 20 websites in it. All websites share the one ip address which is our main server ip 112.140.179.161. 
Server have valid ptr record and spf and dkim records but still mails are delivered in spam folder. Here is the header of the email.

```
     Delivered-To: cutejessie93@gmail.com
    Received: by 10.103.34.3 with SMTP id i3csp443787vsi;
    Thu, 2 Feb 2017 20:31:59 -0800 (PST)
    X-Received: by 10.99.222.17 with SMTP id                f17mr15414610pgg.127.1486096319681;
    Thu, 02 Feb 2017 20:31:59 -0800 (PST)
    Return-Path: <findurdate@findurdate.com.au>
    Received: from server1.1tapcar.com.au ([112.140.179.161])
    by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id o29si19643812pgn.62.2017.02.02.20.31.59
    for <cutejessie93@gmail.com>
    (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
    Thu, 02 Feb 2017 20:31:59 -0800 (PST)
    Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of findurdate@findurdate.com.au 
    designates 112.140.179.161 as permitted sender) client-ip=112.140.179.161;
    Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
    dkim=pass header.i=@findurdate.com.au;
    spf=pass (google.com: domain of findurdate@findurdate.com.au designates 112.140.179.161 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=findurdate@findurdate.com.au
    DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=findurdate.com.au; s=default; h=Date:Message-Id:Content-type:MIME-Version:
    From:Subject:To:Sender:Reply-To:Cc:Content-Transfer-Encoding:Content-ID:Content-Description:Resent-Date:Resent-From:Resent-Sender:Resent-To:Resent-Cc    :Resent-Message-ID:In-Reply-To:References:List-Id:List-Help:List-Unsubscribe:    List-Subscribe:List-Post:List-Owner:List-Archive;    bh=5dJRdmJMQJnkNd/x9jECTZx08/PmJBJyM5K6MsBUufc=; b=hucYdAW3ht6pPTb1jy2EP5gwQn   FufBNcX2r2p+qr21NkCvxGBvq0r727PsDkx50ANx8OfzmUC+8eXhnzkwXkvFZSxFF7qsod7KhyMTh oQon9EFOvxjguKxBMupm7nyEeiv8qDpA6hNLuvQEkQEDewuzV/yR5RVxBZ+WkgoiA+IK9b/p/gNsO   Yl2gIYAXWxImdwiwVfnVpmdQsluKIfhNEZSyo7IB9Gn7oIIt8h1X4Fb5tCLF9J0tATwzV5oX2Afhe  RH63bKByPKAto8UF3jLPEiouhcbJ4KN9yJVwL+PgqRXJmUaOwSjsaXzsdgIsw4HTysxNB6qTvCbs1  9jVclKFg==;
    Received: from buyurcar by server1.1tapcar.com.au with local (Exim 4.87)  (envelope-from <findurdate@findurdate.com.au>) id 1cZVXP-0000Ug-Ra for  cutejessie93@gmail.com; Fri, 03 Feb 2017 15:31:55 +1100
    To: cutejessie93@gmail.com
    Subject: Hello
    X-PHP-Script: findurdate.com.au/api/api.php for 45.127.192.59
    From: <findurdate@findurdate.com.au>
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Content-type: text/html; charset=iso 8859-1
    Message-Id: <E1cZVXP-0000Ug-Ra@server1.1tapcar.com.au>
    Date: Fri, 03 Feb 2017 15:31:55 +1100
    X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it   with any abuse report
    X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - server1.1tapcar.com.au
    X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - gmail.com
    X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [503 500] / [47 12]
    X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - findurdate.com.au
    X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: server1.1tapcar.com.au: authenticated_id:     buyurcar/from_h
    X-Authenticated-Sender: server1.1tapcar.com.au:      findurdate@findurdate.com.au
    X-Source: /usr/bin/php
    X-Source-Args: public_html/findurdate.com.au/api/api.php
    X-Source-Dir: buyurcar.com.au:/public_html/findurdate.com.au/api
```

Every thing looks fine. I don't know where I am doing mistake.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks to inform But I think my problem is more complicated.

Comment: Thanks to inform But I think my problem is more complicated.Now I have changed ip address of all websites from 112.140.179.161 to 112.140.179.162. But still I am getting mail from 112.140.179.161

Answer (score 1):

Your new IP probably does not have valid PTR record. Ask your server provider set PTR to server's hostname.

Answer (score 0):

If by changing the address of your site you mean that you have assigned a dedicated ip address to one of your cPanel accounts, then you should do the following:

`WHM -> Service Configuration -> Exim Configuration Manager`. Scroll down to Domains and IPS and select **On** for *Send mail from account’s dedicated IP address* (by default, in WHM, this is Off). Go to the bottown of the page and click on the blue Save button. This will save your new configuration and restart exim. Now the emails for that cPanel account will be sent using the account's dedicated ip address.

Please keep in mind that you should have a valid PTR record for that dedicated ip address and also adjust the SPF record of your domain and add that dedicated ip address to the record.

If your emails are still going in Gmail's Spam folder try with yahoo/hotmail or other providers just to check if the same happens there.

You could also try to send daily emails to Gmail from different email addresses of your domain and manually mark them as not spam in Gmail.

Your email headers looks just fine. As long as you have a valid hostname, a valid PTR record that matches your hostname, you have SPF/DKIM/DMARC then you're good to go.

There is not that much you can do though. I have a full /24 ip class and all the emails sent from any of the ips from that range are landing in Gmail's SPAM! On yahoo they go straight to Inbox. Same for hotmail.

If your email volume is under 100 emails / day you could use sendgrid as a relay mail server for your domain (you get 40k emails in the first trial month and then 100 free emails / day).

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed reply. We moved the website to new server. And it solved the problem automatically. I hope it will work.

Comment: Later I figured out the problem that my server didn't have reverse dns set up and that was creating problem.

Comment: Ya sure Thanks :)

Comment: Ok, whenever you have time :)